# Group by with gap in date sequence ("gaps and islands")

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to solve a "gaps and islands" by date issue I'm facing (kudos to [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) helping me identify this issue). I want to group the below table by person, office and job while respecting `order by person,from_date`. consider the table below:

```
    declare @temp table(person varchar(25),office varchar(25),job varchar(25),from_date date,to_date date)
    insert into @temp values ('jon','ny','programmer','1/1/2020','1/3/2020');
    insert into @temp values ('jon','ny','programmer','1/4/2020','1/5/2020');
    insert into @temp values ('jon','dc','programmer','1/6/2020','1/7/2020');
    insert into @temp values ('jon','ny','programmer','1/8/2020','1/9/2020');
    insert into @temp values ('lou','ny','programmer','1/1/2020','1/3/2020');
    insert into @temp values ('lou','ny','programmer','1/4/2020','1/5/2020');
    insert into @temp values ('lou','dc','programmer','1/6/2020','1/7/2020');
    insert into @temp values ('lou','ny','programmer','1/8/2020','1/9/2020');
```

the intended output is

[image]

Comment: Why is the DDL always classified? Shall we assume that `from_date` is a `nvarchar(max)` just like every column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  If there are no gaps in the dates, the simplest solution is the difference of row numbers:

```
select person, office, job, min(from_date), max(to_date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by person, office, job order by from_date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by person, office order by from_date) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by person, office, job, (seqnum - seqnum_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This is a general solution:
WITH preceders_and_followers AS (
    SELECT
        b.person,
        b.office,
        b.job,
        b.from_date,
        b.to_date,
        CASE
            WHEN EXISTS (
                SELECT
                    c.*
                FROM
                    ora$ptt_tmp c
                WHERE
                    b.person = c.person
                    AND b.office = c.office
                    AND b.job = c.job
                    AND ( b.from_date - 1 BETWEEN c.from_date AND c.to_date )
            ) THEN
                1
        END AS has_preceder,
        CASE
            WHEN EXISTS (
                SELECT
                    c.*
                FROM
                    ora$ptt_tmp c
                WHERE
                    b.person = c.person
                    AND b.office = c.office
                    AND b.job = c.job
                    AND ( b.to_date + 1 BETWEEN c.from_date AND c.to_date )
            ) THEN
                1
        END AS has_follower
    FROM
        ora$ptt_tmp b
    ORDER BY
        1,
        2,
        3
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    pf1.person,
    pf1.office,
    pf1.job,
    pf1.from_date,
    (
        SELECT
            MIN(pf2.to_date)
        FROM
            preceders_and_followers pf2
        WHERE
            pf1.person = pf2.person
            AND pf1.office = pf2.office
            AND pf1.job = pf2.job
            AND pf2.to_date >= pf1.from_date
            AND has_follower IS NULL
    ) to_date
FROM
    preceders_and_followers pf1
WHERE
    pf1.has_preceder IS NULL
ORDER BY
    1,
    4,
    2,
    3;
```

Comment: for better readability, you should format the code