# increase value of a column by 1 for next row

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have table like

| eventid | seid | rowNo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 900253 | 2 | 1 |
| 900253 | 0 | 2 |
| 900253 | 0 | 3 |
| 900253 | 0 | 4 |
| 942484 | 69 | 5 |
| 942484 | 0 | 6 |
| 942484 | 0 | 9 |

I want to update the subeventid by 1 based on previous value partitioned by eventid
i want get the output table like below

| eventid | seid | rowNo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 900253 | 2 | 1 |
| 900253 | 3 | 2 |
| 900253 | 4 | 3 |
| 900253 | 5 | 4 |
| 942484 | 69 | 5 |
| 942484 | 70 | 6 |
| 942484 | 71 | 9 |

I tried like below query, but unable to get result, and not getting any idea on it,
please help me in it.

```
select eventname, eventid, subeventid,max_seid,seid, rn,
       LAG (seid, 1, 1) OVER ( partition by eventid order by eventname ) as realseid
from newtest
```

Comment: If you use a column in the sample code, you should probably also include it in the sample data.

Comment: `FIRST_VALUE` is probably what you want.

Comment: you can try gaps and island approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67843551/group-by-with-gap-in-date-sequence-gaps-and-islands

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group by with gap in date sequence ("gaps and islands")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67843551/group-by-with-gap-in-date-sequence-gaps-and-islands)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the sample data you've given us, you can use `FIRST_VALUE` to get the first value, and then use `ROW_NUMBER` to add to appropriate value to it:

```sql
SELECT YT.eventid,
       FIRST_VALUE(YT.seid) OVER (PARTITION BY YT.eventid ORDER BY YT.rowNo) +
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YT.eventid ORDER BY YT.rowNo) - 1 AS seid,
       YT.rowNo
FROM dbo.YourTable YT;
```

Comment: For Sql server 2022 you could make use of its new `window` clause for re-use.